# Can I use Maven Cargo plugin to deploy a WAR to 2 different servers (production and dev stages)?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-cargo, cargo-maven2-plugin

I have a project with a Maven Cargo plugin configuration shown below. When I run `mvn cargo:redeploy`, it deploys the current version of the application to server at `AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD`.

Now I want to add a second server, say `EEE.FFF.GGG.HHH`. `EEE.FFF.GGG.HHH` will be the production server and `AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD` - the development/test stage.

Is it possible to use `mvn cargo:redeploy` to deploy the application to different servers (production and test, `EEE.FFF.GGG.HHH` and `AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD`) ? If yes, how should I modify Cargo's plugin configuration below?

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-product</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>[...]</version>
    <name>my-product</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <powermock.version>1.5</powermock.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <container>
                        <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
                        <type>remote</type>
                    </container>
                    <configuration>
                        <type>runtime</type>
                        <properties>
                            <cargo.remote.username>user name</cargo.remote.username>
                            <cargo.remote.password>password</cargo.remote.password>
                            <cargo.hostname>AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD</cargo.hostname>
                            <cargo.protocol>http</cargo.protocol>
                            <cargo.servlet.port>8080</cargo.servlet.port>
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>

                    <!-- Deployer configuration -->
                    <deployer>
                        <type>remote</type>
                    </deployer>
                    <deployables>
                        <deployable>
                            <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
                            <artifactId>my-product</artifactId>
                            <type>war</type>
                        </deployable>
                    </deployables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: that should be possible using executions within the <plugin> configuration. you can add multiple executions, just make sure they have a different id. The pom reference: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html contains some examples.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by @wemu, you can put many executions in your plugin configuration as following :

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <container>
            <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
            <type>remote</type>
        </container>

        <!-- Deployer configuration -->
        <deployer>
            <type>remote</type>
        </deployer>
        <deployables>
            <deployable>
                <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
                <artifactId>my-product</artifactId>
                <type>war</type>
            </deployable>
        </deployables>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <!-- First execution to deploy on AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD -->
        <execution>
            <id>deploy1</id>
            <configuration>
                <type>runtime</type>
                <properties>
                    <cargo.remote.username>user name 1</cargo.remote.username>
                    <cargo.remote.password>password 1</cargo.remote.password>
                    <cargo.hostname>AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD</cargo.hostname>
                    <cargo.protocol>http</cargo.protocol>
                    <cargo.servlet.port>8080</cargo.servlet.port>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <!--  Second execution to deploy on EEE.FFF.GGG.HHH -->
        <execution>
            <id>deploy2</id>
            <configuration>
                <type>runtime</type>
                <properties>
                    <cargo.remote.username>user name 2</cargo.remote.username>
                    <cargo.remote.password>password 2</cargo.remote.password>
                    <cargo.hostname>EEE.FFF.GGG.HHH</cargo.hostname>
                    <cargo.protocol>http</cargo.protocol>
                    <cargo.servlet.port>8080</cargo.servlet.port>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And you can even mutualize some configuration elements outside of the `executions` like that if you need to add more executions you just have to change the user password and IP adress :

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <container>
            <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
            <type>remote</type>
        </container>

        <!-- Common configuration -->
        <configuration>
            <type>runtime</type>
            <properties>
                <cargo.protocol>http</cargo.protocol>
                <cargo.servlet.port>8080</cargo.servlet.port>
            </properties>
        </configuration>

        <!-- Deployer configuration -->
        <deployer>
            <type>remote</type>
        </deployer>
        <deployables>
            <deployable>
                <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
                <artifactId>my-product</artifactId>
                <type>war</type>
            </deployable>
        </deployables>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <!-- First execution to deploy on AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD -->
        <execution>
            <id>deploy1</id>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <cargo.remote.username>user name 1</cargo.remote.username>
                    <cargo.remote.password>password 1</cargo.remote.password>
                    <cargo.hostname>AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD</cargo.hostname>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <!--  Second execution to deploy on EEE.FFF.GGG.HHH -->
        <execution>
            <id>deploy2</id>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <cargo.remote.username>user name 2</cargo.remote.username>
                    <cargo.remote.password>password 2</cargo.remote.password>
                    <cargo.hostname>EEE.FFF.GGG.HHH</cargo.hostname>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```